# how do I compute the number of unique values in a pyarrow array?

Tags: pyarrow, orc

I have a pyarrow `int32` [`ChunkedArray`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.ChunkedArray.html)
containing 18 chunks that I got from an ORC file:

```py
import pyarrow.dataset
import pyarrow.compute
t = pyarrow.dataset.dataset("my/orc/file", format="orc").to_table()
a = t.column("a_column")
print(type(a))
print(a.num_chunks)
print(a.type)
<class 'pyarrow.lib.ChunkedArray'>
18
int32
```

I want to compute the number of unique values in the column. Seems like a straightforward job for [`count_distinct`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.compute.count_distinct.html#pyarrow.compute.count_distinct):

```py
>>> print(pyarrow.compute.count_distinct(a))
36
```

However, [`unique()`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.compute.unique.html#pyarrow.compute.unique) indicates that there are only two non-null values:

```py
>>> print(pyarrow.compute.unique(a))
[
  null,
  100,
  250
]
```

Suggesting that that `count_distinct()` is summed over the chunks. Is this the expected behavior? What is the correct way to get the number of non-null values in array (either chunked or non-chunked)?

Comment: This is pyarrow version `8.0.0` on Python `3.8.6`

Comment: This seems like a bug to me.  I get the same results.  I would expect `pc.count_distinct(pa.chunked_array([[1],[1]]))` to be `1` but it is `2`.  Can you file a [JIRA ticket](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#did-you-find-a-bug)?

Comment: ok. i'll file a ticket

Comment: Arrow JIRA ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARROW/issues/ARROW-16807?filter=allopenissues